# Is a random Wishart matrix $X \sim \mathcal{W}(I_d, n)$ equal in distribution to $U \Lambda U^T$ with $U$ uniform on $O(d)$ and $\Lambda$ chi-square?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, random-matrices, haar-measure

My question is:

> Suppose that $X \sim \mathcal{W}(I_d, n)$ is it true that $X$ is equal in distribution to $U \Lambda U^T$ where: (i) $U$ and $\Lambda$ are independent, (ii) $U$ is drawn uniformly over $O(d)$, and (iii) $\Lambda$ is diagonal with independent entries drawn $\chi^2(n - d + 1)$?

Here is my reasoning.
Suppose that $X$ is a $d \times d$ real Wishart matrix distributed $\mathcal{W}(I_d, n)$,  so that it has density (over the set of positive definite matrices),
$$
f_{n, d}(X) = c_{n, d}~(\det X)^{(n-d-1)/2} \exp(-\mathrm{tr}(X)/2).
$$
Since $X = U \Lambda U^T$ for $U \in O(d)$ and $\Lambda$ a diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_1, \dots, \lambda_d \geq 0$, it follows from above that $f_{n, d}(X) = f_{n, d}(\Lambda(X))$, so that one can equivalently think of $X \sim \mathcal{W}(I_d, n)$ as being generated by first drawing $U$ uniformly over $O(d)$ (using Haar measure), and then sampling $\lambda = (\lambda_1,\dots, \lambda_d)$ with density
$$
g_{n, d}(\lambda) = \tilde c_{n, d} \prod_{i=1}^d \lambda_i^{(n - d - 1)/2} \exp(-\lambda_i/2).
$$
Since the density factorizes, we see that $\{\lambda_i\}$ can be drawn independently with density proportional to
$$
\xi^{(n-d-1)/2} \exp(-\xi/2), 
$$
which is the density of a $\chi^2(n -d + 1)$ random variable.

I would expect a simple statement like this in some textbook. I couldn't find this result, so I am wondering if there is some flaw in my logic above.